# How do I write variadic templates, that can't accept zero arguments?

Tags: function, templates, c++11, parameters, variadic-templates

Here is a variadic template that prints parameters.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void Output() {
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Output(First arg, const Strings&... rest) {
    std::cout<<arg<<" ";
    Output(rest...);
}

int main() {
    Output("I","am","a","sentence");
    Output("Let's","try",1,"or",2,"digits");
    Output(); //<- I do not want this to compile, but it does.

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get this functionality without having the "no parameter" call work, and without having to write two functions every time?

Comment: You can write a one-parameter version instead of a zero-parameter version. You could hide both in a namespace and call them via a function that requires > 0 arguments.

Comment: I answered your question but I'm not sure what you mean by "without having to write two functions every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to keep the separation of the first and the rest of the parameters, you can use:

```
template<typename First, typename ... Rest>
void Output(First&& first, Rest&&... rest) {
    std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);
    int sink[]{(std::cout<<" "<<std::forward<Rest>(rest),0)... };
    (void)sink; // silence "unused variable" warning
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I used perfect forwarding to avoid copying any parameters. The above has the additional benefit to avoid recursion and therefore is likely to produce better (faster) code.

The way I wrote `sink` also guarantees that the expressions expanded from `rest` are evaluated left-to-right - which is important when compared to the naïve approach of just writing a helper function `template<typename...Args>void sink(Args&&...){}`.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7575a1f719751201)

Answer (score 2):

Call the function from a forwarding type function and have a static_assert like this:

```
template <typename ... Args>                                                       
void forwarder(Args ... args) {                                                    
    static_assert(sizeof...(args),"too small");                                    
    Output(args...);                                                               
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see there are two questsions:

1. How to avoid `Output()` calls with no parameters.
2. Is there a simpler way to end the compile time recursion?

My solution to item 1 is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void Output(const T & string) {
    std::cout<<string<<std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Output(const First & arg, const Strings & ... rest) {
    std::cout<<arg<<" ";
    Output(rest...);
}
```

Basically, instead of ending the recursion when the template list is empty, I end it when it only contains one type. There is one difference between the above and the code from the question: if does not output any space after the last item. Instead it just outputs the newline.

For question number two see the answer by Daniel Frey above. I really liked this solution, although it took some time to grasp it (and I upvoted the answer). At the same time I find that it makes the code harder to read/understand and therefore harder to maintain. Currently I would not not use that solution in anything but small personal code snippets.

Comment: +1 for another option for the OP, but you should (as I did) use perfect forwarding to avoid unnecessary overhead. Also, I agree that my solution is not the easiest one to understand, but avoiding recursion is often very important as it can have a *severe* negative impact on code size and performance which I had to witness several times in the wild. The additional complexity is also nicely contained and is not reflected in the interface towards the user. This is why I have my set of tricks to avoid recursion. FWIW, my solution *also* avoid the superfluous last space :)

Comment: @DanielFrey In general I agree regarding perfect forwarding, but for this particular case I think it is unnecassary as the function is "const". Also there is no need to forward to `operator<<()` as it in almost all cases accept a const reference to the value being outputted. Regarding recursion I expect that an optimizing compiler will inline the last calls; although gcc doesn't do this unless you specify at least -O1. See my updated answer.

Comment: Constant references are fine here as well, just don't copy as you orginally did (and the OP as well). For the recursion, it depends on what `operator<<` will do given that you could feed UDTs which have their own version which might be inline/visible and then the optimizer sometimes bails out and start to generate really terrible code.